# Solving pointer casting warnings

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In the below code, I get the warnings mentioned as comments.
Please help me with a solution to these warnings.

```
//**expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char *’**
void inputArray(char ** arr, int size, char toSearch[]);

int search(char ** arr, int size, char * toSearch);
int main() {

  char *array[5] = {0}; //to check if array is empty later
  int size = 5, searchIndex;
  char toSearch[] = "hello";
  array[0] = "hello";

  // **passing argument 1 of ‘search’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]**
  searchIndex = search(array, size, toSearch);

  if (searchIndex == -1) {
    printf("%s does not exists in array.", toSearch);

    //**passing argument 1 of ‘inputArray’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]**
    inputArray(array, size, toSearch);

  } else
    printf("%s is found at %d position.", toSearch, searchIndex + 1);
  return 0;
}

/*search string*/
int search(char ** arr, int size, char toSearch[]) {
  int index = 0;
  // Pointer to last array element arr[size - 1]

  // **warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]**
  int * arrEnd = (arr + size - 1);

  /*
   * Run a loop from start of array to last array element (arr <= arrEnd),
   * until current array element does not match element to search.
   */

  //**warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast**
  while (arr <= arrEnd && *arr != toSearch) {

    printf("not equal: %d \n", index);
    arr++;
    index++;
  }

  //**warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast**
  if (arr <= arrEnd)

    return index;
  return -1;
}

//adding a string if not found in search
void inputArray(char ** arr, int size, char toSearch[]) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == 0) //stores string where ever an empty place is found.
        {
      arr[i] = toSearch;
      printf("added: %s", arr[i]);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: search requires a char** you are giving it a char*

Comment: The best way to solve problems like this is to write code that doesn't require casts.

Comment: C or C++ ?  Pick one.

Comment: This can't be both C and C++, you're going to need to specify which solution you want. C++ has a different approach to solving problems.

Comment: @SidS C only not C++. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @tadman I need in C. Sorry

Comment: You are making something up. Many of the lines you marked do not have any errors. As far as the language is concerned, the first (and only) truly problematic line is `int * arrEnd = (arr + size - 1);`.

Comment: `char *array[5] = {0};` while fine, make sure you understand you are declaring an *array of pointers to char [5]* (an array of 5 pointers to char). So you would generally see this written as `char *array[5] = {NULL};` However, since `0` is a valid Null Pointer Constant (see: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.3 Pointers (p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p3), you are technically correct, but just make sure you don't confuse yourself and just happen to be "technically correct" by sheer luck.

Comment: @David C. Rankin: True. But attractiveness of `{ 0 }` as an *universal* zero-initializer in C is hard to ignore. `{ 0 }` is worthy of being called an *idiom*.

Comment: No complaints there. There is a trifecta of possibilities for being right but without understanding why. `{0}` *universal initializer*, or interpreted as `{0}` array initializer specifying `1 - Null Pointer Constant` and remaining elements initialized zero by default, or `{NULL}` (same just using the `<stddef.h>` macro)

Comment: Both those errors "*`passing argument 1 ...`*" do **not** arise from the code you show. The parameters passed to `search()` and `inputArray()` are correct. You seem to mix up things on your side.

Comment: @dgsomerton: No, in both cases a `char**` is expected and a `char**` is passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function `search`, `arrEnd` is initialized with a value of the same type as `arr` : `+` and `-` operators on pointers do not change type, only `&`, `*` (prefixed) and casting can change pointers type expression. So, just replace :

```
int * arrEnd = (arr + size - 1);
```

with

```
char ** arrEnd = (arr + size - 1);
```

I do not have other warnings with the code you gave (compiled with gcc).